# How to choose and download specific release version of Azure Bicep?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, release-management, azure-bicep

In my docker image, I currently specify the download of the bicep module [from GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/bicep/tags) as suggested in the [Azure Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/install).

```
# Install Bicep
RUN curl -Lo bicep https://github.com/Azure/bicep/releases/latest/download/bicep-linux-x64
RUN chmod +x ./bicep
RUN mv ./bicep /usr/local/bin/bicep
```

Now, I want to fix the version of the bicep to be `v0.23.1`. Do you know how to achieve that? I played around with the link, but I did not manage to get the path. For example, I tried without success:

```
 curl -Lo bicep https://github.com/Azure/bicep/releases/download/v0.23.1/bicep-linux-x64
```

I suppose I need something more sophisticated than `curl -Lo`. Can someone give me a hint on how I get specific release assets from git?

Solution:
For reference the above curl statement with version works for the docker file. I had a problem with my ps rule configurations, which I was trying to fix at the same time. For those who might need it, this is how the `ps-rule.yml` can be configured:

```
requires:
  # Require PSRule for Azure v1.30.1
  PSRule: '2.9.0'
  PSRule.Rules.Azure: '1.30.1'
```

Comment: the command `curl -Lo bicep https://github.com/Azure/bicep/releases/download/v0.23.1/bicep-linux-x64` wokrs for me. what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: Ok yeah in the end I had a mistake in the `ps-rule.yml`  and the docker file was actually fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `Dockerfile` (or adapt it to fit into your existing `Dockerfile`):

```
FROM ubuntu:23.04

RUN apt-get update -qq -y && apt-get install -qq -y curl libicu-dev
RUN curl -Lo bicep https://github.com/Azure/bicep/releases/download/v0.23.1/bicep-linux-x64 && \
    chmod +x bicep && \
    mv bicep /usr/local/bin/bicep
```

You also need to install `libicu-dev` in order to run `bicep`.

Then fire up a container and test:

```
root@b20d3a793186:/# bicep --version
Bicep CLI version 0.23.1 (b02de2da48)
```